# report viewer page break

Tags: reportviewer, page-break

I have a problem with ReportViewer in my application. I have a main report that consist of subreports. There is a subreport that fit into a page. But  reportviewer inserts one more clean page and only after this clean page the next subreport starts. I don't want reportviewer to insert clean page. How to fix this problem? Please help.